# File Path issue in Java Axis2 WebService

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, wso2, apache-axis

I'm developing a web service using axis2 & tomcat .  There I use a data.xml file to store some information. When I give the Absolute Path for the data.xml file, everything works fine. But I am looking for a way to give the file path in relative to the source file. To achive that I have tried several methods.

(the deployed aar file is located under `C:/tomcat/webapps/axis2/WEB-INF/service.aar` )

This is my folder structure.

```
+Project
|-src
|-data
  |-data.xml
```

1. I have added the data folder to the build path.
2. I have tried to include the file as `./data/data.xml`

But it failed. Can anyone suggest me a best/recommended way to do this?

-Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research, I found that it is impossible to do it. It should be a absolute path for the xml file.